# How to instantiate a mx comobox in a pure actionscript project on flash builder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I am trying to use the following code in a pure actionscript project ( no mxml ) on flash builder :

```
import mx.controls.ComboBox;
...
...

var cmb:ComboBox

....
addChild(cmb)
....
```

But when compiling, the combobox does not appear. I can see it in the mxml version though.

Comment: How do you instantiate the instance of cmb?  You need something like "cmb = new ComboBox()".  This should work, as a lot of the mx and spark controls are actually implemented in raw ActionScript.

Comment: I tried doing that. But could not see anything on the stage. About spark, i read somewhere, that they can only be used via mxml. Cannot find the link right now though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, mx and spark can be used unless it's mxml project. But anyways i solved, by using the combobox in flash ide, and creating a swc file. And then using fl.controls.ComboBox in the flash builder.